# Angular form to create en entry used to edit the entry

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

here's what i am trying to do:
i have a json that gives me albums. i have on the left side the list of albums and on the right a form i use to add albums and refresh the json.

form appears on click. click on button = create new, click on album = update.
i want the form to also work for editing. so if i click on an album title i get the data and change save button to update.

i get the json, post, edit form using php on the server side.

i set [this example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cezarneaga/pqgyquw1/3/) in a simplified version. below the html.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-sm btn-red" ng-click="albumForm = true;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add album</button>
<div ng-repeat="album in albums">
        <a ng-model="currentAlbum" ng-change="onClick()" ng-click=" $parent.albumForm = true; ">{{ album.title }}</a>
</div>
```

i am new to angular and learning by doing :)
could you please help me out?

thanks,
Cezar

Comment: I think you've described what you are doing, but you haven't asked a question.

Comment: sorry:) the problem i am having is that i cannot get it to work. when i click on the album title it does not open the form with populated data.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/72jvx2kp/1/

Comment: this is it. let me see if i can make it work for me. thank you immensely for this.

Comment: @pixelbits i have a followup question if i may. 
i have some select boxes in this form and the only way to get the data inside when i follow the links is to use say....
`<select ng-model="editingAlbum.title" ng-options="a.title as a.title for a in albums"></select>`
the issue is that if i do this i dont get the entire object which i need in order to do some calculations later on in the view.
if i do...
`<select ng-model="editingAlbum.title" ng-options="a.title for a in albums"></select>`
i get the object but then the select isnt populated :(

Comment: forgot to mention, i am talking about data from an object
`this.albums = [
        {
            id: '1',
            albumCode: 'ABC',
            albumRate: '33'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            albumCode: 'DEF',
            albumRate: '45'
        }
};`

Comment: Use "item.title for item in albums track by item.id". ngModel will be bound to the item

Comment: thanks, but this doesnt work for me. it brings the list of options alright but nothing is selected in the <select>. 
only when i say item.title as item.title the value is selected. but then as mentioned before i dont have the rest from the object

Comment: Sorry, I meant  "item as item.title for item in albums track by item.id".

Comment: nope. this doesnt work either.

Comment: It should work. Perhaps raise another question